# The default value for the date field will be "01/01/0001 00:00:00" on my create view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, date

I am facing the following problem in using date correctly in my asp.net mvc application:-

1. i have a patient Object that contains a DateOfBirth property with a data type of (date) at the sql server 2008 database.

But the problem on the `Create` view the `DateOfBirth` initial value will be `“01/01/0001 00:00:00”`, so how can i force the DateOfbirth field to be empty on the Create view.
BR

Comment: Use `DateTime?`/`Nullable<DateTime>`?

Comment: why should i set it to DateTime?/Nullable<DateTime>. Since the Dateofbirth can not be null as specified in the database!!!!!!

Comment: Your _view_ should be nullable, but that doesn't mean you can't add `[Required]` validation or `[DisplayFormat]` attributes to your view to make it at least functionally/visually appealing before inserting it in to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use a nullable `DateTime` type (`DateTime?`) or accept that you'll never have a patient with a date of birth (DoB) that year (unless Jesus is a patient?) and treat those values as if null/empty.  In that second case you'd have to modify aggregate commands (averages min/max) to filter out all those with that specific value.

Since everyone should have a DoB, it should really be enforced at record creation time that a DoB is provided (none provided - no record created)... so how often will this even be an issue?

Comment: why should i set it to DateTime?/Nullable<DateTime>. Since the Dateofbirth can not be null as specified in the database!!!!!!

Comment: When you define a variable it has to have some value when it's first instantiated.  Nullable - it'll be null.  Otherwise, in the case of a DateTime it's `DateTime.MinValue`.  You can add object validation to force a value assignment (constructor requires DoB or storage routine throws error if value isn't set) but the moment that memory space is first allocated it still has to have some value.  If you want that some value to be empty, you need to make it a nullable type.